# Implement SMS gateway on django project

Tags: python, django, sms-gateway

I know some SMS API, they are too expensive for the goal of my application.
Is there a way to create an SMS server to alert users, then the user can send feedbacks, my application will easily reply based on some key codes. I heard about [Rapid SMS](http://rapidsms.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/backends/index.html#rapidsms-backends). What comes to my mind:

- A modem
- SIM card
- A daemon software (`kannel` maybe)
- Web application with django

Any help will be gracefull!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twilio](https://www.twilio.com) supports sending SMS messages, and I believe it can also carry out certain actions on receiving an SMS. It has a [Python API client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) so it should in principle be practical to integrate it with your application.

Comment: i used twilio, for sending about 3000 per day, it's too expensive, i made some researchs, do you think Kannel with python django will be good for the project ? that's the problem, i i'm looking for the way to do, better is to send sms with my national money, i'm not living in USA.

Comment: I think there's probably not going to be much better than Twilio. Any SMS gateway that is too cheap runs the risk of being abused by unscrupulous businesses, and 3000 a day is a fair few.

Comment: OK i understand, but do you know other which not like Twilio ?

Comment: There's plenty around but you're unlikely to find one cheap enough. Maybe you should consider whether you need to send so many and if it could be done using another method.

Comment: Some friends suggest to me to use Kannel or AT Command on linux.
if i have a model with a SIM Card, i will be able to configure and send SMS.
Rapid SMS (Django framework).
In my country, the price of twilio is worth 2 times of that from here.
i still use twilio, but i want to change.

Comment: Could you do what you need with push notifications? Many web browsers now support them so it might be a better fit?